# Prestashop 1.6 - Tracking Number Not Displayed in "Shipped" Template After Storing in DB and Orders Page

Tags: templates, prestashop-1.6

I have created a module to insert tracking links upon new orders that uses certain carrier. I have checked that the tracking number is inserted in database and also found in Orders page. In database, it is stored in orders_carrier.

```
$orderinfo = new Order($params['id_order']);
$carrierinifo = new Carrier($orderinfo->id_carrier);

if ($carrierinifo->name=='Standard Delivery') {
   $ordercarrier = new OrderCarrier($orderinfo->id_carrier);
   if ($ordercarrier->tracking_number=='') {
       $ordercarrier->tracking_number = $this->config['TRACK_PRE'].str_pad($orderinfo->id, $this->config['DIGI'], "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
       Db::getInstance()->update(
       'order_carrier',
       array('tracking_number'=>$ordercarrier->tracking_number),
       'id_order='.$orderinfo->id
       );
```

I cannot fathom why the tracking number is not displayed in "Shipped" template. It will only be successfully displayed if I click edit (under the shipping tab in Orders page) and re-save the tracking number. (When the tracking number is already saved and displayed in Orders page). This is the extra step and I am omitted from automating this step.

I have assigned the variable in shipping template that I am using and it will trigger when I change to "Shipped" status.

Is there anyone facing the same problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use :

```
$order = new Order($params['id_order']);
$tracking = 'NUMBER TRACKING';
$id_order_state = 'NUMBER OF STATUS';

if (!empty($tracking) && !is_array($tracking)) {
    $id_order_carrier = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
        SELECT `id_order_carrier`
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_carrier`
        WHERE `id_order` = ' . (int) $order->id);
    if ($id_order_carrier) {
        $order_carrier = new OrderCarrier($id_order_carrier);
        $order_carrier->tracking_number = $tracking;
        $order_carrier->update();
    } else {
        $order->shipping_number = $tracking;
    }

}

if ($id_order_state && ($order->current_state != (int) $id_order_state)) {
        $new_oh = new OrderHistory();
        $new_oh->id_order = $order->id;
        $new_oh->id_order_state = (int) $id_order_state;
        $new_oh->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $new_oh->add();
        $new_os = new OrderState((int) $id_order_state, $order->id_lang);
        Module::hookExec('actionOrderStatusUpdate', array('newOrderStatus' => $new_os, 'id_order' => (int) $order->id), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);
}
```

Regards

Comment: I have managed to successfully store tracking number in database and also assign to an order. I am facing an issue whereby I have to click edit and re-save for it to be displayed in template.

Comment: If you take my code it will cleanly insert the tracking code, change the status and all without having to reclick anywhere.

Comment: Sounds good. But I would also like to understand, why is my code not working when I tried to use the variable as I have stored the tracking number and assign to order? I have assigned the variable in shipping template.

Comment: You have to go through the Prestashop class and call the hooks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get to the root of the problem. I was actually updating the carrier_order, tracking number. I should also update orders, shipping_number. Good to know it works now.

I did not realise this. Sharing this for anyone looking for a solution to a similar issue.

Thank you.